# How to solve open ubuntu in grub

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

Si alguien puede decirme como resuelvo esto....

If someone can tell me how I solve this ....

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

GRUB>
```

Comment: I'm unclear what your question or issue is. Please revisit your question and re-edit in the form of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be about the rudimentary emergency shell (not bash) in GRUB.

You have to read the information given, what the actual problem is. There is the option to start from grub with 'noquiet nosplash' by editing the bootline (e) to see the startup prozess and get an impression, where it fails (at least whether early or late, when the messages rush too fast).

I guess with quit or exit, you exit the grub shell, bringing you back into the grub boot menu.

You might read logfiles in /var/log from the grub shell, for instance, to find messages from failed bootups. For beginners, unfamiliar with every shell, the grub shell is normally of not so much help, except they get detailled advice, probably from a friend at phone or linux user group.